# I need just the prices extracted from the strings below

Tags: python, string, strip

My program scrapes from various websites and for the product prices; some of them return the price as `\\n\\n        9.99 €\\n      \\n` and others return the price as `\\n\\n          6.99 €\\n        \\n\\n        4.99 €\\n      \\n`.

I would like just the number gotten out of the string. I have tried using `.strip('\\n')` but it wont seem to remove any of the  `\\n` s.

Comment: try with smt like `import re ; re.search(r'(\d*\.\d{,2})',  '\n\n 9.99 €\n \n' ).group(1)` Yue can use regular expression to validate your data, [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the newline characters, you can use `string.replace("\n", "")` to replace all `\n` characters with the empty string. In your example this would get you `" 6.99 €  4.99 € "`.

If you want to get these as actual numbers, you can strip the outer whitespace with `string.strip` and then split between Euro symbols with `string.split`, for example: `s.replace("\n", "").strip().split("€")`. For your example, this would output `['6.99 , '  4.99 ', '']`, a list of strings.

You can get the actual numbers out with a list comprehension. Tying it all together:

```
string = "\n\n 6.99 €\n \n\n 4.99 €\n \n"
string_to_list = string.replace("\n", "").strip().split("€")
numbers = [float(s.strip()) for s in string_to_list if s != ""]
```

For your example, this yields `[6.99, 4.99]`.

Answer (score 0):

If these are the only characters that is cluttering your strings, you could remove them, then split the prices into a list.

```py
s = "\\n\\n          6.99 €\\n        \\n\\n        4.99 €\\n      \\n"

l = s.replace("\\n", "").replace("€", "").split()
```

This will produce the list ['6.99', '4.99']

Answer (score 0):

Validate your data with a regular expression, short [*regex*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). The type of data will influence the type of pattern to be used. Here I used: `r'(\d*\.\d{,2})'` which means find a digit (or no digit) followed by . and zero or digits, so it is designed for floating numbers.

```
import re

string_values = ['\\n\\n        9.99 €\\n      \\n', '\\n\\n          6.99 €\\n        \\n\\n        4.99 €\\n      \\n']

pattern = re.compile(r'(\d*\.\d{,2})')

values = list(map(float, sum([pattern.findall(s) for s in values], [])))

print(values)
```

Output

```
[9.99, 6.99, 4.99]
```

Remarks:

- `findall` since there are more occurrence of the pattern in the same string... it get them all
- `sum(iterable, [])` is used to flat the nested list (there are better solutions as `itertools.chain`, ...)
- `map` is used to cast every string into a float